# Delete operation in RecyclerView not doing anything

Tags: android, sqlite, android-recyclerview, android-sqlite

Here is the Adapter (**RVAdapter_Reminders.java**)

```
static List<DatabaseModel> dbList;
static Context context;
DBHelper dbHelper;
private int position;

public RVAdapter_Reminders(Context context, List<DatabaseModel> dbList) {
    this.dbList = new ArrayList<DatabaseModel>();
    this.context = context;
    this.dbList = dbList;
}

public int getPosition() {
    return position;
}

public void setPosition(int position) {
    this.position = position;
}

@Override
public RVAdapter_Reminders.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.rv_reminder_template, null);
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(itemLayoutView);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final RVAdapter_Reminders.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.title.setText(dbList.get(position).getTitle());
    holder.description.setText(dbList.get(position).getDescription());
    holder.address.setText(dbList.get(position).getAddress());
    holder.buttonViewOptions.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //creating a popup menu
            PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(context, holder.buttonViewOptions);
            //inflating menu from xml
            popup.inflate(R.menu.reminder_rv_menu);
            popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                    setPosition(holder.getAdapterPosition());
                    return false;
                }
            });
            popup.show();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onViewRecycled(ViewHolder holder) {
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(null);
    super.onViewRecycled(holder);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return dbList.size();
}

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnCreateContextMenuListener {

    public TextView title, description, address, buttonViewOptions;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.task_title);
        description = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.desc_title_text_tv);
        address = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.address_title_text_tv);
        buttonViewOptions = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.buttonViewOptions);
        itemView.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        menu.add(Menu.NONE, R.id.menu_delete_option,
                Menu.NONE, R.string.delete_menu_text);
    }
}
```

Here is the Activity where the adapter is inflating data inside the RecyclerView

**Reminders.java**

```
 FloatingActionButton fab;
DBHelper dbHelper;
List<DatabaseModel> dbList;
RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_reminders);
    fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);

    try {
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Reminders");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);
    dbList = new ArrayList<DatabaseModel>();
    dbList = dbHelper.getDataFromDB();

    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv_reminders);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    // using a linear layout manager
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

    //specifying an adapter
    mAdapter = new RVAdapter_Reminders(this, dbList);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    registerForContextMenu(mRecyclerView);

}


public void addReminder(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Reminders.this, NewReminder.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Reminders.this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int position = -1;

    try{
        position = ((RVAdapter_Reminders)mRecyclerView.getAdapter()).getPosition();
    }catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d(String.valueOf(this), e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }

    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.menu_delete_option:
            onReminderDelete(dbList.get(position).getTitle());
            break;
    }

    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}

private void onReminderDelete(String title){
        dbHelper.deleteARow(title);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}
```

DeleteRow function in the DBHelper class:

```
public void deleteARow(String title) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(REMINDERS_TABLE, RemindersContract.TITLE + " = " + title, null);
    Log.d(String.valueOf(this), title + " deleted");
    db.close();
}
```

and finally, **RemindersContract** class:

```
 public static final String TITLE = "title";
```

Answer (score 1):

your `mAdapter` has still the values with deleted value. You must update your `dbList` to have current values.

```java
private void onReminderDelete(String title){
    dbHelper.deleteARow(title);
    dbList.remove(/* value that you want remove*/);
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: I implemented what u said

dbHelper.deleteARow(title);
            dbList.remove(position);
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

 but it's still not doing anything.

Comment: why make you `dbList` and `context` `static` in your adapter? make it non static. also the first initialisation of dbList in adapter is obsolete, besause you initialize it with `this.dbList = dbList`

Comment: Umm. did what u recommended but still the same results.
btw, there should be Log.d entry of the item after it gets deleted but that's not there either. So, I think the problem might be because the deleteARow() function isnt even getting called?

Comment: make in `onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item)` `System.out.println("context menu click")` to see if it ever will be executed

Comment: As expected, the nothing in the log (onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item)) 
So, the issue is somewhere with the menu.

Comment: the are a lot of ways, to create context menu with `RecyclerView`. I have no expirience with your way of implementation. Try to find, where the problem occours or choose some other for context menu.

Comment: Yeah, there was an issue with my menu implementation.
I fixed the issue. Although, your response was also helpful. Thanks :)

I'll update the code by answering my question later.